# Selenium: Session not created - the target machine actively refused it (when launching dozens of parallel FF instances)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, webdriver

I recently upgraded to Selenium version 4 and it seems to be causing more harm than good.

When I try running a single (or a small number) of WebDriver instances in parallel via the command:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxOptions);
```

Selenium launches as expected. However, when I try running dozens of instances at one time I get the following errors:

```
1649745964100   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:50788
1649745964101   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:55599
1649745964103   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:62022
1649745964105   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:57781
1649745964106   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:60187
...


1649745964966   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "C:\\MyApp\\Files\\Firefox\\firefox.exe" "--marionette" "--remote-debugging-port" "52303" "-no-remote" "-profile" "C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rust_mozprofile49eIxp"
1649745964969   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "C:\\MyApp\\Files\\Firefox\\firefox.exe" "--marionette" "--remote-debugging-port" "62028" "-no-remote" "-profile" "C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rust_mozprofile1awb0N"
1649745964971   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "C:\\MyApp\\Files\\Firefox\\firefox.exe" "--marionette" "--remote-debugging-port" "62582" "-no-remote" "-profile" "C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rust_mozprofileX7Iv6n"
1649745964972   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "C:\\MyApp\\Files\\Firefox\\firefox.exe" "--marionette" "--remote-debugging-port" "53475" "-no-remote" "-profile" "C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rust_mozprofilehOG354"
1649745964973   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "C:\\MyApp\\Files\\Firefox\\firefox.exe" "--marionette" "--remote-debugging-port" "54847" "-no-remote" "-profile" "C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rust_mozprofile6m4dJU"
...

1649745965124   geckodriver::marionette DEBUG   Waiting 60s to connect to browser on 127.0.0.1:57736
1649745965124   geckodriver::marionette DEBUG   Waiting 60s to connect to browser on 127.0.0.1:57783
1649745965124   geckodriver::marionette DEBUG   Waiting 60s to connect to browser on 127.0.0.1:57757
1649745965125   geckodriver::marionette DEBUG   Waiting 60s to connect to browser on 127.0.0.1:57740
1649745965125   geckodriver::marionette DEBUG   Waiting 60s to connect to browser on 127.0.0.1:57782
...

1649745966721   RemoteAgent DEBUG   CDP enabled
1649745966721   RemoteAgent DEBUG   CDP enabled
1649745966721   Marionette  INFO    Marionette enabled
1649745966721   Marionette  INFO    Marionette enabled
1649745966721   RemoteAgent DEBUG   CDP enabled
...

1649745967088   geckodriver::marionette TRACE   No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (os error 10061). Retrying in 100ms
1649745967089   geckodriver::marionette TRACE   No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (os error 10061). Retrying in 100ms
1649745967090   geckodriver::marionette TRACE   No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (os error 10061). Retrying in 100ms
1649745967104   geckodriver::marionette TRACE   No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (os error 10061). Retrying in 100ms
1649745967104   geckodriver::marionette TRACE   No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (os error 10061). Retrying in 100ms
...

1649745968454   Marionette  TRACE   Received observer notification toplevel-window-ready
1649745968471   Marionette  TRACE   Received observer notification toplevel-window-ready
1649745968477   Marionette  TRACE   Received observer notification toplevel-window-ready
1649745968477   Marionette  TRACE   Received observer notification toplevel-window-ready
1649745968486   Marionette  TRACE   Received observer notification toplevel-window-ready
...

console.error: Region.jsm: "Failed to fetch region" (new Error("TIMEOUT", "resource://gre/modules/Region.jsm", 419))
console.error: Region.jsm: "Error fetching region" (new Error("TIMEOUT", "resource://gre/modules/Region.jsm", 772))
console.error: Region.jsm: "Failed to fetch region" (new Error("TIMEOUT", "resource://gre/modules/Region.jsm", 419))
console.error: Region.jsm: "Error fetching region" (new Error("TIMEOUT", "resource://gre/modules/Region.jsm", 772))
console.error: Region.jsm: "Failed to fetch region" (new Error("TIMEOUT", "resource://gre/modules/Region.jsm", 419))
...

1649746120764   geckodriver::browser    DEBUG   Browser process stopped: exit code: 1
1649746120767   geckodriver::browser    DEBUG   Browser process stopped: exit code: 1
1649746120769   geckodriver::browser    DEBUG   Browser process stopped: exit code: 1
1649746120770   geckodriver::browser    DEBUG   Browser process stopped: exit code: 1
1649746120770   geckodriver::browser    DEBUG   Browser process stopped: exit code: 1
...

org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException
...

org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
```

What's stopping Selenium from creating new browser sessions? It's obviously not a Firewall issue as the code runs without issue when I limit to a handful of browsers.

I'm using Java. I never had an issue launching dozens of browsers in Selenium v3.

What changed in v4 that's causing this issue? I'm using **local** `WebDriver` (**NOT** Remote Web Driver)

**Update**:

As requested by @undetected Selenium please see additional debug info below:

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (os error 10061)
Build info: version: '4.1.3', revision: '7b1ebf28ef'
System info: host: 'MyHost', ip: '17X.XX.XX.X', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_191'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, moz:debuggerAddress: true, moz:firefoxOptions: {binary: C:\MyApp\Files\Firef..., log: {level: trace}, prefs: {browser.cache.disk.capacity: 1024, datareporting.policy.dataSubmissionPolicyAccepted: false, dom.max_chrome_script_run_time: 0, dom.max_script_run_time: 0, dom.popup_maximum: 200, dom.webnotifications.enabled: false, general.useragent.override: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10...., media.peerconnection.enabled: false, network.proxy.http: 127.0.0.1, network.proxy.http_port: 24000, network.proxy.socks: 127.0.0.1, network.proxy.socks_port: 24000, network.proxy.socks_remote_dns: true, network.proxy.type: 1}}}], desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, moz:debuggerAddress: true, moz:firefoxOptions: {binary: C:\MyApp\Files\Firef..., log: {level: trace}, prefs: {browser.cache.disk.capacity: 1024, datareporting.policy.dataSubmissionP
olicyAccepted: false, dom.max_chrome_script_run_time: 0, dom.max_script_run_time: 0, dom.popup_maximum: 200, dom.webnotifications.enabled: false, general.useragent.override: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10...., media.peerconnection.enabled: false, network.proxy.http: 127.0.0.1, network.proxy.http_port: 24000, network.proxy.socks: 127.0.0.1, network.proxy.socks_port: 24000, network.proxy.socks_remote_dns: true, network.proxy.type: 1}}}}]
Apr 12, 2022 1:12:15 PM org.openqa.selenium.os.OsProcess destroy
INFO: Unable to drain process streams. Ignoring but the exception being swallowed follows.
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: The stop timeout of 2000 ms was exceeded (Exit value: -559038737)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.PumpStreamHandler.stopThread(PumpStreamHandler.java:295)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.PumpStreamHandler.stop(PumpStreamHandler.java:180)
    at org.openqa.selenium.os.OsProcess.destroy(OsProcess.java:135)
    at org.openqa.selenium.os.CommandLine.destroy(CommandLine.java:139)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.stop(DriverService.java:281)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:154)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:567)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:248)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:164)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:118)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:106)
    at webdriverX.WebDriverX.launchNewFireFoxWebDriver(WebDriverX.java:150)
    at webdriverX.WebDriverProfile.getTMPFirefoxProfile(WebDriverProfile.java:1030)
    at webdriverX.WebDriverProfile.getTMPFirefoxProfile(WebDriverProfile.java:1165)
    at webdriverX.WebDriverProfile.requestWebDriver(WebDriverProfile.java:735)
    at fulfilment.source.pages.ProductPage.ProductTestSuit.scrapeField(ProductTestSuit.java:89)
    at fulfilment.source.pages.ProductPage.ProductTestSuit$1.run(ProductTestSuit.java:52)
```

**Update #2**:

Please see some of the actual code used to launch dozens of instances of Firefox WebDriver:

```
    public static void scrapeField(List<String> urlList) throws Exception {
    for (String url : urlList) {
        
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    
                    
                    scrapeField(url);
                } catch (Exception v) {
                    System.out.println(v);
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

The method `scrapeField()` essentially calls the method `getTMPFirefoxProfile()` which returns 1 instance of `Firefox WebDriver` per URL as seen below:

```
public static WebDriver getTMPFirefoxProfile(String ipAddress, Integer port) throws IOException, {
    
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", path_to_exe_file);

    FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
    firefoxOptions.addPreference("browser.cache.disk.capacity", 1024);

    firefoxOptions.addPreference("dom.popup_maximum", 200);
    firefoxOptions.addPreference("dom.webnotifications.enabled", false); 
    firefoxOptions.addPreference("media.peerconnection.enabled", false); 
    
    firefoxOptions.addPreference("media.peerconnection.enabled", false);

    firefoxOptions.addPreference("datareporting.policy.dataSubmissionPolicyAccepted", false);
    firefoxOptions.addPreference("dom.max_chrome_script_run_time", 0); 
    firefoxOptions.addPreference("dom.max_script_run_time", 0); 
    firefoxOptions.addPreference("media.peerconnection.enabled", false); 

    firefoxOptions.setLogLevel(FirefoxDriverLogLevel.TRACE);

    firefoxOptions.addPreference("general.useragent.override", rndUserAgentStr);
                
    firefoxOptions.addPreference("network.proxy.type", 1); 

    firefoxOptions.addPreference("network.proxy.socks", ipAddress); 

    firefoxOptions.addPreference("network.proxy.socks_port", port); 

    firefoxOptions.addPreference("network.proxy.http", ipAddress);  
                    
    firefoxOptions.addPreference("network.proxy.http_port", port); 
                    
    firefoxOptions.addPreference("network.proxy.socks_remote_dns", true); 
                
    firefoxOptions.setBinary(path_to_binary_firefox);


    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxOptions);


    return driver;
}
```

Comment: Update the question with the complete error stacktrace associated with _`SessionNotCreatedException`_

Comment: @undetectedSelenium I updated the question with the requested info

Comment: @undetectedSelenium After performing additional tests, I noticed that if I set a 5 second delay between each launch I am able to complete all 100 launches without issue.. Of course it is not acceptable to add such a delay in production as we need to launch dozens of browsers at a time but this might be useful in debugging above error.. somehow when many instances are being launched at once something happens that prevents everyone of them from being launched.. the question is what's happening..

Comment: How do you initiate dozen of institutions? Can you update the question with your actual code trials please?

Comment: @undetectedSelenium I updated the OP with code being used to initialize dozens of WebDriver instances.. Please see Update 2. Thanks.

Comment: The stack trace showed a timeout exception after 2 seconds. You can extend that time using Chrome or edge options. I would think Firefox supports it too.